# I cannot coverage RN Elements via FlowType

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

i would like to use [FlowType](https://flowtype.org). But i have problems with coverage all element in React-Native. I have two version of one component. And i have same problems on same places.

Here is my component. I did it as in this [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos-flow/src/components/TodoList.js):

```
// @flow
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
 } from 'react-native';
import styleConstants from '../../styles/style-constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textField: {
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    backgroundColor: styleConstants.colorBasicBackground,
  },
});

export type Props = {
  +accessibilityLabel: string,
}

const textInputTest = ({
  accessibilityLabel,
}: Props): ReactElement => (
  <TextInput
    accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
    style={styles.textField}
  />
);

export default textInputTest;
```

and this is flow coverage: 
[image: flow coverage]
When i delete `styles` and prop `style` then nothing happened. `<TextInput ... />` will mark red.

and this is second version of same component:

```
// @flow
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
 } from 'react-native';
import styleConstants from '../../styles/style-constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textField: {
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    backgroundColor: styleConstants.colorBasicBackground,
  },
});

export type Props = {
  +accessibilityLabel: string,
  keyboardType?: string,
  multiline?: boolean,
  +onChangeText: () => void,
  style?: StyleSheet.Styles,
  defaultValue?: string,
}

export default class TextField extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    keyboardType: 'default',
    multiline: false,
    style: null,
  };

  render() : React.Element<any> {
    const {
      accessibilityLabel,
      keyboardType,
      multiline,
      onChangeText,
      style,
      defaultValue,
    } : Props = this.props;

    return (
      <TextInput
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        autoCapitalize={'none'}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        multiline={multiline}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        style={[styles.textField, style]}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

and flow coverage:
[image]

I have same red error on same places. How can i coverage `TextInput` and `styles`?

Thank you for the answers...

**UPDATE:**
my `.flowconfig`:

```
[ignore]
; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]android.js

; Ignore "BUCK" generated dirs
<PROJECT_ROOT>/\.buckd/

; Ignore unexpected extra "@providesModule"
.*/node_modules/.*/node_modules/fbjs/.*

; Ignore duplicate module providers
; For RN Apps installed via npm, "Libraries" folder is inside
; "node_modules/react-native" but in the source repo it is in the root
.*/Libraries/react-native/React.js
.*/Libraries/react-native/ReactNative.js

#APP related
.*/node_modules/react-render-hook/.*
.*/node_modules/unexpected-htmllike-jsx-adapter/.*
.*/node_modules/unexpected-htmllike-raw-adapter/.*
.*/node_modules/unexpected-htmllike-testrenderer-adapter/.*
.*/node_modules/flow-coverage-report/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/coverage/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-coverage/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/gulpfile\.js

[include]

[libs]
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow
flow/

[options]
emoji=true

module.system=haste

experimental.strict_type_args=true

munge_underscores=true

module.name_mapper='^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)$' -> 'RelativeImageStub'

suppress_type=$FlowIssue
suppress_type=$FlowFixMe
suppress_type=$FixMe

suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe\\($\\|[^(]\\|(\\(>=0\\.\\(3[0-8]\\|[1-2][0-9]\\|[0-9]\\).[0-9]\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIssue\\((\\(>=0\\.\\(3[0-8]\\|1[0-9]\\|[1-2][0-9]\\).[0-9]\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)?:? #[0-9]+
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixedInNextDeploy
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIgnoreShellowRenderingTest
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIgnoreMockDataTest

unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters=true

[version]
^0.38.0
```

Comment: what does your .flowconfig look like?